# WebSockets with Android: where's the URL?

Tags: c#, android, websocket, xmpp, chat

I'm currently working on a chat app for Android, and I understand that it needs an intermediary server as a point of contact between clients. I also get that XMPP is a tried and tested solution but however I'm primarily a C# developer and would like to invest my time in WebSockets, because from what I've read I believe it's both **fast** and **lightweight**, though it needs a handshake of some sort.

So right now I've downloaded [WebSocket4Net](http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/) (which is a fork from [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/)?). I'm able to create a `WebSocket` object with a local URL of sorts, and I understand that [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/android/) is a viable WebSockets client library for Android. What I *don't understand* however, is how I'm going to get my Android client to connect to the web server (without a LAN connection, but rather over the Internet).

Right now I think that a possible solution would be to expose a WCF endpoint which then plays well with the `WebSocket`, but then again that would add to the roundtrip time, defeating the purpose of WebSockets implementation in the first place... (lightweighted-ness!) I might as well just make do with simply WCF services as that point of contact.

My question then is: what's the URL that my Android client will interact with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, WebSocket4Net **is not a fork of SuperWebSocket** but instead a WebSocket client so it was totally different from what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer anyway @VinZ, I'm looking forward to getting a solution on this question: [Alchemy Websockets: Can't host server on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642075/websocketserver-cant-host-server-on-azure).

It's really troubling because my Websocket server works locally but not on Azure!

Answer (score 1):

Matt,

1. Create a c# console application with WebSocket4Net listening on a specific port (say 8000).
2. Then deploy this application on a server with a static IP or a domain name (say example.com) assigned to it.
3. Now in android app you connect to this ip or domain address using Autobahn. i.e the url will be **ws://example.com:8000**

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hmm. So on my application server I start the `WebSocket` with this line `this.webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:13370/");`? But I can't seem to connect from my client (or http://www.websocket.org/echo.html, as a matter of fact)...

Comment: What is your server ip address matt? It has be a static ip so that anybody on the internet can hit it.